# Cannot import function name from another file

Tags: python

I'm going to go ahead and ask question # 2,345,651 about file imports in python.  But I've been on SO for the last hour and have just sunk two hours in the drain trying to port a function from one directory into another.

My situation:

I have the following application with the current file structure:

```
trading/

 -- app/
    models.py
 -- db/
    engine.py
```

`trading`, `app`, and `db` all have an `__init__.py` file inside of them.

At first I tried different combinations of this:

```
from trading.db.engine import load_engine
from db.engine import load_engine
from .db.engine import load_engine
from ..db.engine import load_engine
```

I get the following error messages, respectively:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'trading'
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'db'
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

I also know there is the `PYTHONPATH` value that you can set, and I've done that too.

Here are screenshots of my current environment variables in Windows System Manager:

For my entire system:

[image]

For my own username:

[image]

But yet I cannot use the `load_engine` function from the `engine.py` in the `db` folder for the `models.py` file in the `app` folder.

Genuinely looking for help.  Thank you.

Comment: Which file and/or command are you running? What does `import os; print(os.environ.get('PYTHONPATH'))` output if you add it to the top of the file?

Comment: Since `app` and `models` are both modules as well, do yo need them to function outside of `trading`? Do you import either `load_engine` or `db` into `trading` in its `__init__.py`? If so, you could also `from trading import load_engine` if `trading` is on the path (or `from trading.db import load_engine`, if you import `db` instead of `load_engine` from `trading`)

Comment: By the way, the reason there are so many `import` questions on SO, as you mention, is that people tend to start with complicated setups without first trying to understand the simpler mechanics - it's not immediately obvious, but if you try to really understand how it works in simple cases, putting the more complicated ones together becomes straightforward as well.

Comment: Since `trading` is the package, its _parent_ directory needs to be in python's module search path. So `PYTHONPATH = C:\Users\Jonat`. More generally, you want to install packages and that means setup.py.  https://docs.python.org/3/distributing/index.html.